# Tailwind: Hover effect on one social Icon

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the below react component that uses tailwindcss. On hover over a single icon, both icons are applied mr-4. I want the hover effect to be applied on single hovered icon. thanks

```
import { FaLinkedin, FaGithub } from "react-icons/fa";

const SocialLinks = () => {
  return (
    <div className="fixed top-50% right-0 flex mt-48">
      <ul>
        <li className="mr-2 hover:mr-4">
          <a
            className="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-blue-800 text-white"
            
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in"
          >
            <FaLinkedin size={16} />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="mr-2 hover:mr-4">
          <a
            className="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-gray-300 text-gray-800"
            
            href="https://github.com"
          >
            <FaGithub size={16} />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SocialLinks;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `li` elements are inside a ul and they are left aligned in there. So when you increase the margin of one of them, the size of the whole `ul` is increased. And so the other `li` is also moved since it is positioned relative to the `ul`.

You can just change the `ul` to `<ul class="flex flex-col items-end">` and it will work as expected.

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ospQWvG0I1